# Why does this error appear when running the application? "Failed to build iOS app in flutter"

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

Welcome
I'm having a problem running the app on ios and this is the error code

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
```

Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            9.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
2022-08-14 16:34:22.736 xcodebuild[9219:98973] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-08-14 16:34:22.737 xcodebuild[9219:98973] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
Writing result bundle at path:
/var/folders/37/ylwrs_293m1cdjjpb8mscp8c0000gp/T/flutter_tools.CCnmEB/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirVu9DVC/temporary_xcresult_bundle

```
Failed to package /Users/macbookshop/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_aliii.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build system
note: Planning
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in dependency order

Result bundle written to path:
    /var/folders/37/ylwrs_293m1cdjjpb8mscp8c0000gp/T/flutter_tools.CCnmEB/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirVu9DVC/temporary_xcresult_bundle
```

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.

Answer (score 0):

What I did when faced the same issue was:

- Cleaned the build folder using **Shift+Command+K** first.
- Then closed the current simulator and opened another simulator *(in your case, close iPhone 11 pro MAX and open iPhone 12 pro simulator)*
- Ran these command in the terminal at root of the project `pod clean` and `pod install`.
- And again built the iOS app from Xcode.

This worked for me